# Making a form read-only for a certain user type

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a login form with a combo box for the user type (Admin, User) and a text box for the password. The code for the form is as follows.

```
Private Sub txtPassword_AfterUpdate()

If IsNull(Me.cboUser) Then
    MsgBox "You need to select a user!", vbCritical
    Me.cboUser.SetFocus
Else
    If Me.txtPassword = Me.cboUser.Column(2) Then
        If Me.cboUser.Column(3) = True Then
            MsgBox "Password does not match, please re-enter!", vboOkOnly
            Me.txtPassword = Null
            Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        End If
        DoCmd.OpenForm "FE1"
        Me.Visible = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Password does not match, please re-enter!", vboOkOnly
        Me.txtPassword = Null
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cboUser_AfterUpdate()
Forms!frmLogin!cboUser.Column (2)
End Sub
```

If the log in is as a User, when they get to the FE1 form, I want them just to be able to read the form, and not make any changes. The code I've been trying to use for this is as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Open()
If Forms!frmLogin!cboUser.Column(2) = 2 Then
   Me.AllowEdits = False
   Me.AllowAdditions = False
   Me.AllowDeletes = False
Else
   Me.AllowEdits = True
   Me.AllowAdditions = True
   Me.AllowDeletes = True
End If
End Sub
```

But I keep getting the error:

> The expression On Open you entered as the event property setting
>   produced         the following error: Procedure declaration does not
>   match description of       event or procedure having the same name.
>
> *The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a   user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
>   *There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.

It's possible I've just been looking at this for too long, but I can't figure  out where I've gone wrong!?

Comment: Make sure your `Form.OnOpen` property is set to `"[Event Procedure]"`. This error tends to occur when it isn't.

Comment: Fair warning here, if these passwords are just for making the DB a little easier to use that's fine but hopefully you know this offers no security whatsoever.

Comment: Form.OnOpen is set to "[Event Procedure]".

Comment: For the purposes of this database, high level security isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Form_Open` procedure has the wrong signature, missing the `Cancel` parameter.

It must be:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
```

Don't write event procedures by hand, let Access create them.

**Edit**

I suggest you completely remove the `Form_Open` sub. Then let Access create it from the property sheet.

And you can simplify your code by using a variable like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim AllowWriting As Boolean
    AllowWriting = Not (Forms!frmLogin!cboUser.Column(2) = 2)

    Me.AllowEdits = AllowWriting 
    Me.AllowAdditions = AllowWriting 
    Me.AllowDeletes = AllowWriting 

End Sub
```

or even shorter with the [RecordsetType Property](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RecordsetType-Property-dbe9dd7a-cc73-4539-aaa7-9e6b55034052):

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If Forms!frmLogin!cboUser.Column(2) = 2 Then
        Me.RecordsetType = 2    ' Snapshot = read-only
    Else
        Me.RecordsetType = 0    ' Dynaset = read-write
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When I add the `Cancel` parameter, I get the error: `Compile error: Method or data member not found`, then when I click OK takes me to my code where it highlights `Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)`.